# How to get methods declared in Base class using Reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, reflection, windows-store-apps

I am trying to invoke methods using Reflection in Windwos 8 store application. I tried to get list of all methods from a base class method  using this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().DeclaredMethods.

```
var methodList = base.GetType().GetTypeInfo().DeclaredMethods;
```

I am able to get all
methods declared in the child class and invoke them. But i am unable to get list of methods defined in the base class.
what is wrong with the approach? 
this project built using .Net for Windows store

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you are trying to do, since you seem to mix up base class and child class. `this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().DeclaredMethods` would get you the CHILD CLASS methods.

Answer (score 5):

```
GetType().GetRuntimeMethods()
```

This method gave what i wanted. 
Got all the methods present inside the object during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it manually:

```
public static class TypeInfoEx
{
    public static MethodInfo[] GetMethods(this TypeInfo type)
    {
        var methods = new List<MethodInfo>();

        while (true)
        {
            methods.AddRange(type.DeclaredMethods);

            Type type2 = type.BaseType;

            if (type2 == null)
            {
                break;
            }

            type = type2.GetTypeInfo();
        }

        return methods.ToArray();
    }
}
```

and then

```
Type type = typeof(List<int>);
TypeInfo typeInfo = type.GetTypeInfo();
MethodInfo[] methods = typeInfo.GetMethods();
```

Answer (score -1):

Notice that `.DeclaredMethods` is a property on the class. This is working as intended.

The code you want (I think) is

```
var methodList = base.GetType().GetMethods();
```

Comment: There is no such method named GetMethods().

Comment: @Noob I am looking at the documentation of the method right now. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: But not applicable for Windows 8 store apps

Comment: I also checked the supported in before posting. It is availble in both PCL and Windows Phone 8.1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb(v=vs.110).aspx#versionsTitleToggle

Comment: I ve no idea. But then why cant i  see that method?