# Understanding inherited and base items in a list

Tags: c#, list, inheritance

This is a question that might perhaps be foolish, but I can't seem to reason my way around it so I have come here for some thoughts. It's about inheritance and lists.

Alright, so I have two classes: TestClass and DerivedTestClass. DerivedTestClass is derived from TestClass. Both classes have a method called 'Method1'.

These are both very simple methods. They just have a message box saying what method is being accessed. In fact, let me write the code just to remove ambiguity:

```
public void Method1(String typeName)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Base method 1 + Type: "+typeName);
}
```

This is for the base class (TestClass).

```
public void Method1(String typeName)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Derived method 1 + Type: "+typeName);
}
```

This is for the derived class (DerivedTestClass).

Next I created an instance of both of these and called the Method1 for each. And it's exactly as you'd expect. When I called it for the base class I for the first message box, and when I called the derived class I got the second one.

No mysteries so far, but now we get to the part where my understanding seems to be lacking.

I create a List into which I add both instances I have created: the instance of the base class and the instance of the derived class. Then I created a foreach loop which went through each item in the list and called Method1, as follows:

```
foreach (var tc in listT)
{
    tc.Method1(tc.GetType().Name);
}
```

In both cases the base method is called. Now in one respect I get that as the list itself is the type of the base class. The problem is if I look at the types. If I ask the first item in the list what its type is, it will say TestClass. If I ask the second item in the list what its type is, it will say DerivedBaseClass.

Now one can solve this by casting each item within the list to its own type. But it can require a long list of if statements based on how many derived types you have. Also, and I suppose this is the heart of the problem, I'm just confused about ever having to cast something to that which it already is. If the item is a DerivedBaseClass (as evidenced by the GetType()), it seems odd that I have to cast that to DerivedBaseClass. Can I rely on GetType in these situations? Should it come with an asterisk that says 'well the memory declared is only enough for the base class, and while this is a derived class, it's currently in the form of a base class'?

So you could say I'm a bit confused and looking for clarification.

Comment: *"let me write the code just to remove ambiguity"* - there is still ambiguity in question because you miss either `virtual` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31175769/1997232)) or `new` (not sure how) [modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/modifiers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. You aren't overriding `Method1`, you are hiding it in the derived class so you can consider these methods as completely different things entirely.
2. Your list only contains references to the base type, and as such will only call the methods it exposes.

To fix this, change your types to something like this, note the `virtual` base method and the `override` in the derived class:

```
public class BaseType
{
    public virtual void Method1(String typeName)
         //^^^^^^^ This
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Base method 1 + Type: "+typeName);
    }
}

public class DerivedType : BaseType
{
    public override void Method1(String typeName)
         //^^^^^^^^ And this
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Derived method 1 + Type: "+typeName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. A nice and easy explanation and solution.

Comment: @TheFaithfulLearner, it seems you have ignored [compiler warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0108), never do so in the future.